# Laravel cursor pagination loop inside console command

Tags: php, laravel, pagination, cursor

How can I loop through all the pages of a cursor pagination inside a Laravel console command?

```php
$paginator = User::query()->orderBy('id')->cursorPaginate(2);
    
while ($paginator->hasPages()) {
    foreach ($paginator->items() as $item) {
        $this->info($item->id);
    }

    $paginator = $paginator->nextCursor();
}
```

I am stuck in looping, please help.

Comment: What is your current issue ? (You can remove `query()` and leave it as `User::orderBy('id')`)

Comment: Use [`chunk`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#chunking-results) to iterate through an entire table in pages. `cursorPaginate` is meant to be an alternative to `paginate` and is mostly used for front-end presentation purposes

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it is the best approach but you can do something like this:

```
$query = User::query()->orderBy('id');
$paginator = $query->cursorPaginate(20, ['*'], 'myCursorId');

while ($paginator->hasPages()) {
    foreach ($paginator->items() as $item) {
        $this->info($item->id);
    }

    $next = $paginator->nextCursor();
    $paginator = $query->cursorPaginate(20, ['*'], 'myCursorId', $next);
}
```

The `nextCursor()` function return the point of begging for the new query.
You can also use `chunk` but probably it will consume more memory than cursor approach.

Comment: FYI - You want a do while here, otherwise the code inside your while loop won't run if you have less than 20 items.

Answer (score 0):

Add this function macro to the laravel query builder in ServiceProvider,then you can loop any model:

```
 Builder::macro('cursorPaginateItemsGenerator',
        /**
         * @param int $perPage
         * @param array $columns
         * @param string $cursorName
         * @param callable|null $callback
         * @return \Generator
         */
        function (int $perPage = 100, array $columns = ['*'], string $cursorName = 'cursor', ?callable $callback = null) {
            $cursorPaginator = $this->cursorPaginate($perPage, $columns, $cursorName);
            do {
                yield is_callable($callback) ? array_map($callback, $cursorPaginator->items()) : $cursorPaginator->items();
            } while ($cursorPaginator->hasMorePages() && $cursorPaginator = $this->cursorPaginate($perPage, $columns, 'cursor', $cursorPaginator->nextCursor()));
        });
```

use like this:

```
foreach(User::query()->orderBy('id')->cursorPaginateItemsGenerator(20,['*'],'cursorId') as $users){
        dd($users);
    }
```

$users contain max 20 items for every foreach loop